# numpy.polyfit has no keyword 'cov'

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I'm trying to use polyfit to find the best fitting straight line to a set of data, but I also need to know the uncertainty on the parameters, so I want the covariance matrix too. The  online documentation  suggests I write:

> > polyfit(x, y, 2, cov=True)

but this gives the error:

> > TypeError: polyfit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cov'

And sure enough help(polyfit) shows no keyword argument 'cov'.

So does the online documentation refer to a previous release of numpy? (I have 1.6.1, the newest one). I could write my own polyfit function, but has anyone got any suggestions for why I don't have a covariance option on my polyfit?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the reference to `polyfit` in 1.6: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html.  Note that there is no `cov` parameter.  You were probably looking at the documentation for numpy 1.7 (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that comes from a library, I find that using [scikits.statsmodels](http://scikits.appspot.com/statsmodels) is a convenient choice. In statsmodels, regression objects have callable attributes that return the parameters and standard errors. I put an example of how this would work for you below:

```
# Imports, I assume NumPy for forming your data.
import numpy as np
import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm

# Form the data here
(X, Y) = ....

reg_x_data =  np.ones(X.shape);                      # 0th degree term. 
for ii in range(1,deg+1):
    reg_x_data = np.hstack(( reg_x_data, X**(ii) )); # Append the ii^th degree term.


# Store OLS regression results into `result`
result = sm.OLS(Y,reg_x_data).fit()


# Print the estimated coefficients
print result.params

# Print the basic OLS standard error in the coefficients
print result.bse

# Print the estimated basic OLS covariance matrix
print result.cov_params()   # <-- Notice, this one is a function by convention.

# Print the heteroskedasticity-consistent standard error
print result.HC0_se

# Print the heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix
print result.cov_HC0
```

There are additional robust covariance attributes in the `result` object as well. You can see them by printing out `dir(result)`. Also, by convention, the covariance matrices for the heteroskedasticity-consistent estimators are only available *after* you already call the corresponding standard error, such as: you must call `result.HC0_se` prior to `result.cov_HC0` because the first reference causes the second one to be computed and stored.

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is another library that probably provides more advanced support for these operations.

**Non-library function**

This might be useful when you don't want to / can't rely on an extra library function.

Below is a function that I wrote to return the OLS regression coefficients, as well as a bunch of stuff. It returns the residuals, the regression variance and standard error (standard error of the residuals-squared), the asymptotic formula for large-sample variance, the OLS covariance matrix, the heteroskedasticity-consistent "robust" covariance estimate (which is the OLS covariance but weighted according to the residuals), and the "White" or "bias-corrected" heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance.

```
import numpy as np

###
# Regression and standard error estimation functions
###
def ols_linreg(X, Y):
    """ ols_linreg(X,Y) 

        Ordinary least squares regression estimator given explanatory variables 
        matrix X and observations matrix Y.The length of the first dimension of 
        X and Y must be the same (equal to the number of samples in the data set).

        Note: these methods should be adapted if you need to use this for large data.
        This is mostly for illustrating what to do for calculating the different
        classicial standard errors. You would never really want to compute the inverse
        matrices for large problems.

        This was developed with NumPy 1.5.1.
    """
    (N, K) = X.shape
    t1 = np.linalg.inv( (np.transpose(X)).dot(X) )
    t2 = (np.transpose(X)).dot(Y)

    beta = t1.dot(t2)
    residuals = Y - X.dot(beta)
    sig_hat = (1.0/(N-K))*np.sum(residuals**2)
    sig_hat_asymptotic_variance = 2*sig_hat**2/N
    conv_st_err = np.sqrt(sig_hat)

    sum1 = 0.0
    for ii in range(N):
        sum1 = sum1 + np.outer(X[ii,:],X[ii,:])

    sum1 = (1.0/N)*sum1
    ols_cov = (sig_hat/N)*np.linalg.inv(sum1)

    PX = X.dot(  np.linalg.inv(np.transpose(X).dot(X)).dot(np.transpose(X))   )
    robust_se_mat1 = np.linalg.inv(np.transpose(X).dot(X))
    robust_se_mat2 = np.transpose(X).dot(np.diag(residuals[:,0]**(2.0)).dot(X))
    robust_se_mat3 = np.transpose(X).dot(np.diag(residuals[:,0]**(2.0)/(1.0-np.diag(PX))).dot(X))

    v_robust = robust_se_mat1.dot(robust_se_mat2.dot(robust_se_mat1))
    v_modified_robust = robust_se_mat1.dot(robust_se_mat3.dot(robust_se_mat1))

    """ Returns:
        beta -- The vector of coefficient estimates, ordered on the columns on X.
        residuals -- The vector of residuals, Y - X.beta
        sig_hat -- The sample variance of the residuals.
        conv_st_error -- The 'standard error of the regression', sqrt(sig_hat).
        sig_hat_asymptotic_variance -- The analytic formula for the large sample variance
        ols_cov -- The covariance matrix under the basic OLS assumptions.
        v_robust -- The "robust" covariance matrix, weighted to account for the residuals and heteroskedasticity.
        v_modified_robust -- The bias-corrected and heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix.
    """
    return beta, residuals, sig_hat, conv_st_err, sig_hat_asymptotic_variance, ols_cov, v_robust, v_modified_robust
```

For your problem, you would use it like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Define or load your data:
(Y, X) = ....

# Desired polynomial degree
deg = 2;

reg_x_data =  np.ones(X.shape); # 0th degree term. 
for ii in range(1,deg+1):
    reg_x_data = np.hstack(( reg_x_data, X**(ii) )); # Append the ii^th degree term.


# Get all of the regression data.
beta, residuals, sig_hat, conv_st_error, sig_hat_asymptotic_variance, ols_cov, v_robust, v_modified_robust = ols_linreg(reg_x_data,Y)

# Print the covariance matrix:
print ols_cov
```

If you spot any bugs in my computations (especially the heteroskedasticity-consistent estimators) please let me know and I'll fix it asap.

Comment: Thanks for you help, a couple of bugs though. hastack should be hstack, I assume. I also first have to turn my X and Y in to 2D arrays (i.e. .shape = (2000,1), not (2000,). Then I get the issue 't2 = (np.transpose(X)).dot(Y), ValueError: matrices are not aligned', because the reg_x_data is now not the same size as Y.

Comment: Yeah, I had changed the `hastack` typo a bit ago, I'm not sure if you're screen didn't refresh or something. Yes, I assume that `X` and `Y` are 2-D arrays. You could add some simple code at the beginning of `ols_linreg` to reshape 1-D arrays into 2-D arrays if needed.

Comment: I added a solution that uses the scikits.statsmodels library, in case you really needed a library solution. I also modified my code to be a bit more efficient and vectorized. I've checked the function posted here against the scikits.statsmodels regression results, and my function matches their results out to about 6 decimal places, on several of their provided test data sets.