# Need Python polynomial fit function that returns covariance

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, covariance, polynomial-math

I want to do least-squares polynomial fits on data sets (X,Y,Yerr) and obtain the covariance matrices of the fit parameters. Also, since I have many data sets, CPU-time is an issue, so I'm seeking an analytical (=fast) solution. I found the following (non-ideal) options:

`numpy.polyfit` does the fit, but doesn't take into account the errors Yerr, nor does it return the covariance;

`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` does accept Yerr as an input (in the form of weights), but doesn't return covariance either;

`scipy.optimize.curve_fit` and `scipy.optimize.leastsq` can be tailored to fit polynomials and return the covariance matrix, but - being iterative methods - these are much slower than the `polyfit` routines (which yield an analytical solution);

Does Python provide an analytical polynomial fit routine that returns the covariance of the fit parameters (or do I have to write one myself :-) ?

***Update:***
It appears that in Numpy 1.7.0, `numpy.polyfit` now not only *does* accept weights, but also returns the covariance matrix of the coefficients ... So, issue resolved! :-)

Comment: Look into mpfit or kmpfit.  http://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfit.html

Comment: According to the link, this is another (general) iterative solver. Because of speed, I'm seeking an analytical (=non-iterative) solution - which is perfectly possible for polynomials.

Comment: Would statsmodels be something? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pystatsmodels/paCNa5sXbOo http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html

Comment: @joris This link might indeed be useful, gonna look into it. Thnx

Comment: The code for doing a polynomial fit is very simple...why not just adapt the existing numpy routine to return the covariance matrix as well?

Answer (score 0):

You want a fast weighted least squares model that returns the covariance matrix without additional overhead? In general, the right covariance matrix will depend on the data generating process (DGP) because different DGP (say Heteroscedasticity of errors) imply different distributions of parameter estimates (think White vs. OLS standard errors). But if you can assume WLS is the right way to do it, and I believe you would use the asymptotic variance estimate for beta for WLS, (1/n X'V^-1X)^-1,  where V is the weighting matrix created from Yerrs. That's a pretty simple formula if numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit is working for you.

I looked for an online reference but couldn't find one. But see Fumio Hayashi's Ecomometrics, 2000, Princeton University press, p. 133 - 137 for a derivation and discussion.

Update 12/4/12:
There is another stack overflow question that comes close:
[numpy.polyfit has no keyword 'cov'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261972/numpy-polyfit-has-no-keyword-cov) that has a nice explanation (with code) of how to use scikits.statsmodels to do what you want. I believe you'll want to replace the line:

```
result = sm.OLS(Y,reg_x_data).fit()
```

to

```
result = sm.WLS(Y,reg_x_data, weights).fit()
```

Where you define weights as a function of Yerr as before with numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit. More details on using statsmodels with WLS over at 
the [statsmodels website](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/regression.html#introduction).

Comment: Thnx, I know the formulas to do the calculations, I was only hoping that the corresponding code had already been implemented in Python/Numpy - which doesn't seem to be the case :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using scipy.linalg.lstsq

```
import numpy as np,numpy.random, scipy.linalg
#generate the test data
N = 100
xs = np.random.uniform(size=N)
errs = np.random.uniform(0, 0.1, size=N) # errors
ys = 1 + 2 * xs + 3 * xs ** 2 + errs * np.random.normal(size=N)

# do the fit
polydeg = 2
A = np.vstack([1 / errs] + [xs ** _ / errs for _ in range(1, polydeg + 1)]).T
result = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, (ys / errs))[0]
covar = np.matrix(np.dot(A.T, A)).I
print result, '\n', covar

>> [ 0.99991811  2.00009834  3.00195187]
[[  4.82718910e-07  -2.82097554e-06   3.80331414e-06]
 [ -2.82097554e-06   1.77361434e-05  -2.60150367e-05]
 [  3.80331414e-06  -2.60150367e-05   4.22541049e-05]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work fine for a single data set, or even multiple sets as long as in each set the errors are the same. However, in general the errors may be different for different sets, yielding a different matrix A in each case. The `linalg.lstsq` algorithm then needs to be placed in a loop - and that's exactly what I do not want (because of computational speed). Also in this general case, the solution may be calculated in one huge array operation, which will speed up things dramatically. As far as I know such a function does not exist (that is: yet - since I'm gonna build it myself)

Comment: If you will have different datasets, you have to build the matrix again (which is very lightweight operation anyway), and solve the system again. There is no other way. I don't think there is any gain of combining the different chi-square problems into one big one, because the performance of matrix calculations will be ~ N^2, so you'll be better solve multiple small problems than one big with a lot of params.

Comment: You are right, but combining the different Chi-square problems into one big one was not what I meant. I'm aiming at solving the individual problems in parallel in one single 3D-array operation, with the different data sets along the 3rd dimension. I already tried this 'quick and dirty', and in my case (2 million data sets) it is 500 times (!) faster than looping over the individual data sets.